# Recurring Character Counter

Tags: python-3.6

Good day:

would like to ask a simple question regarding my code on Python 3.6

I want to count all the characters that repeats itself

here is the sample of the code that i worked on:

```
name01 = input("1st Name: ")

ch_name01 = []
bl_char = False
i = 0
for ch in name01:

    i = 0

    for ich in ch_name01:

        bl_char = False

        if ich[i][0] == ch:
            bl_char = True
            #ch_name01[i][1] = ch_name01[i][1] + 1
            #print(str(ch_name01[i][0]) + " - " + str(ch_name01[i][1]))

        if not bl_char:
            i = i + 1


    if bl_char == False:
        ch_name01.append([ch, 1])

print(ch_name01)

#print(ch_name01)
```

for example input `"aabbccddef"`
would like to return `a = 2, b = 2, c = 2, d = 2`

but it will return error message

`"TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable"`

on `if ich[i][0] == ch:`

Comment: You may want to consider `from collections import Counter`, or storing the `item, count` as a `key: value` pair in a `dictionary`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a dictionary will make your life so much easier here.

```
name01 = input("1st Name: ")

ch_name01 = {}             # New dictionary 
for ch in name01:          # For every char in the input string
    if ch in ch_name01:    # If that char already has an entry in the dictionary
        ch_name01[ch] += 1 # increment that char's entry's integer value
    else:                  # the char hasn't been added to the dictionary yet
        ch_name01[ch] = 1  # add a new dictionary entry with an integer value of 1
print(ch_name01)
```

Supplying input of `aabbccddef` produces:

```
{'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 2, 'd': 2, 'e': 1, 'f': 1}
```

**Edit:**
I added code comments to explain what each line is doing

Comment: hey checked your post and it works. just asking. new in python. which part of the code that appends the character? is it in ```ch_name01[ch] = 1``` ?